# urllib.request SSL Connection Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm trying to parse the data from this url:

https://www.chemeo.com/search?q=show%3Ahfus+tf%3A275%3B283

But I think this is failing because the website uses SSL TLS 1.3. How can I enable my Python script, below, to connect using SSL in urllib.request?

I've tried using an SSL context but this doesn't seem to work.

This is the Python 3.6 code I have:

```
import urllib.request
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
chemeo_search_url = "https://www.chemeo.com/search?q=show%3Ahfus+tf%3A275%3B283"

print(chemeo_search_url)

with urllib.request.urlopen(chemeo_search_url, context=scontext) as f:
    print(f.read(200))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS`

[From the docs on "PROTOCOL_SSLv23":](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

> Deprecated since version 2.7.13: Use PROTOCOL_TLS instead.

**note:**

Be sure to have the CA certificate bundles installed, like on a minimal build of alpine linux, busybox, the certs have to be installed. Also sometimes if python wasn't compiled with SSL support, it might be necessary to to do so. Also depending on which version of OpenSSL has been compiled will determine which features for SSL will be usable.

Also note chemeo site doesn't use TLSv1.3 ... it is still experimental and not all that secure at the time of this writing, they currently support tls 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 using "letsencrypt" as their cert provider.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS` gives me a cannot find reference error, the only option which appears in PyCharm is `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23`. As an aside, I've tried using the `requests` package, with the verify option set to `False` and this failed too! 

You said something about compiling python with SSL support; how would I go about doing this?

Comment: @LarsaSolidor what OS, what version of openssl, what version of python, have you accidentally deleted the ca-certificates? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` ?